# Outlook Com Add-In Deployment & Extensibility Issue

Tags: c#, com, ms-office, add-in, extensibility

I'm a developer writing an add-in for Outlook2003/2007 using C#, Visual Studio 2005. I'm also using the COM add-in wizard (not using VSTO, I have a Connect.cs). The program successfully runs with visual studio installed on my machine but when I try to deploy the software I am getting weird behavior.

I have a logging system set up to write a few Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2 events (OnBeginShutdown, OnDisconnection, OnConnection, and OnStartupComplete) to a log file. When I run Outlook on the deployed machine my add-in does not startup up. However, when I exit Outlook I do see data in my log, but its showing that only the events OnDisconnection and OnBeginShutdown were fired. How come OnConnection and OnStartupComplete are not firing? I'm worried its a references/DLL issue but why would the other events fire and not these two?

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out, for anyone out there who may run into this: we had our managed dll set to register for interop (in project properties)...make sure this box is unchecked! This was overriding the shim registration