# How to deploy extensibility.dll for Outlook 2003 plug-in

Tags: dll, com, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I have to deploy Outlook 2003 COm plug-in.  I have .Net4.0 framework and PIA for office 2003 installed on my machine. While registering the plugin using RegASM.exe myplugin.dll , I am getting error

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'Extensibility,
```

The extensibility.dll was not present at

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\
```

How to deploy the 2003 plugin and the extensibility.dll?  Do we need to bundle in installer?  Is it legal to bundle?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Possibley related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/936945/58737